# Tensorization of entropy: confusion regarding conditional entropy

Tags: probability, entropy, high-dimensional

I'm reading High-Dimensional Statistics by Wainright.

In the book, entropy for random variable $Z \geq 0$ is defined as $H(Z) = E[Z \log Z]- E[Z] \log E[Z]$. My understanding is that $H(Z)$ is a constant, not a random variable.

Next, for $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, we define the conditional entropy as $H(\exp(\lambda f_k(X_k)|x_{/k}) = H(\exp(\lambda f(x_1, \ldots x_{k-1}, X_k,x_{k+1},\ldots x_n))$, where $f_k$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that sends $x_k$ to $f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots x_n)$, where $x_{/k} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, a fixed vector that's missing the $k$-coordinate.

The book then says $H(\exp(\lambda f_k(X_k)|X_{/k})$ is a random variable(and not a number), which I do not understand. It seems like $H(\exp(\lambda f_k(X_k)|X_{/k}) = H(\exp(\lambda f(X_1, \ldots X_{k-1}, X_k,X_{k+1},\ldots X_n))$, and this seems like it should be a number since it's just entropy of a random variable.

EDIT: To be more precise, according to the book, I'm understanding to be $H(\exp(\lambda f_k(X_k)|X_{/k})$ the entropy of the random variable $\exp(\lambda f(X_1, \ldots, X_n))$. And since it's a entropy of a random variable, it's a number not a random variable, which is contrary to what the book says.

Below is the screenshot of relevant section.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Somehow my comment got deleted. But let me reiterate: wasn't the author clear enough to indicate it is conditional expectation?

Comment: @User1865345 I don't think it's explicitly stated as conditional expectation, but yes I assume it is. I just don't know exactly what's being conditioned on what.

Answer (score 1):

The entropy is just a number, because it's just an expectation, but the conditional entropy is a random variable, because it's a **conditional** expectation.  That is, $$\mathbb{H}\left(e^{\lambda f_k(X_k)}|X^{\backslash k}  \right)$$
is a function of $X^{\backslash k}$, which is random, and so is a random variable.

Comment: But my confusion is that using the definition, the conditional entropy just seems to be entropy of the function $e^{\lambda f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)}$, so I'm not seeing how it's a random variable.

Comment: No, the expectations in defining conditional entropy are taken over all the other $X_i$ but not the one you left out. For entropy, the expectations are taken over all of them.

Comment: so you're saying $H(e^{\lambda f_k(X_k)}|X_{/k}) = E(e^{\lambda f_k(X_k)} \log e^{\lambda f_k(X_k)}|X_{/k}) - E(e^{\lambda f_k(X_k)}|X_{/k})\log E(e^{\lambda f_k(X_k)}|X_{/k})$?

Answer (score 0):

At first, some simple example with conditional expectation. Say you have two random variables $X, Y$ with $Y$ taking discrete values. You can then calculate the expectation of $X$ given $Y=y$. If this value exists for all $y$ you can define the mapping
$$
g: y \mapsto \frac{\mathbb{E} ( X \mathbb{I}_{\{Y = y\}})}{\mathbb{P} (Y = y)} .
$$
This mapping is often also denoted via $\mathbb{E}( X \vert Y = y)$.
If $g$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, then $g(Y)$ is a random variable and it is a *version* of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E} (X \vert Y )$. The same can be done if you substitute $X$ by $f(X,Y)$ for some function $f$. In that case you would get $\mathbb{E}( f(X,Y) \vert Y)$ and this is not the same as $\mathbb{E} f(X,Y)$ since we first calculate the mapping for all possible values $y$ and then plug in $Y$ in the last step.

Now the situation you describe is very similar, but instead of taking the expectation of $X$ or $f(X,Y)$ for some fixed $y$ we calculate the entropy of $e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)}$ for some fixed $x_{\backslash k}$. If we can do this for all choices of $x_{\backslash k}$ and if the resulting mapping
$$
g: x_{\backslash k} \mapsto \mathbb{H}( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)}) = \mathbb{H}( e^{\lambda f_k (x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1}, X_k, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n)})
$$
is measurable, then we can plug in $X_{\backslash k}$ into $g$ and obtain a random variable $g(X_{\backslash k})$. As above, we can denote this random variable as  $\mathbb{H}( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k})$. The text is then a bit vague whether we should call $\mathbb{H}( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k})$ or its expectation the *conditional entropy*, but for the subsequent lemma this is not important.

Also note that $\mathbb{H}( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k})$ is not a conditional expectation, since it is calculated via the entropy formula in (3.2) and not via an expectation. Also it does not use a term like $\mathbb{I}_{\{Y = y\}}$ in the calculation. As a result, I doubt that $\mathbb{H} ( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k})$ is equal to
$$
\mathbb{E} ( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \log e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k}) - \mathbb{E} ( e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k} ) \log \mathbb{E} (e^{\lambda f_k (X_k)} \vert X_{\backslash k} )
$$
as you asked in a comment below Thomas Lumley's answer.